# Installation of 64bit Ubuntu 14.4.2 on an 32 bit operating system

Tags: 14.04

I wish to install 64bit Ubuntu 14.04.02 on an 32 bit operating system with 4 GB RAM (Intel i5-3330 CPU @ 3.00 GHz as a dual OS alongwith Windows 7 OS.  Let me know is there any future problems with this installation.

Comment: what is the output of this command : `lscpu`

Comment: what do you mean with *"on an 32 bit **operating** system"*??? - i'm pretty sure your machine is a 64bit-system (but anyway check it like *begueradj* suggested)! and then take the 64bit-iso, install it like suggested in one of the hundreds of tutorials and every thing will be fine! ;-)

Comment: ...or if you just want to try something and you are afraid of messing up your current OS, consider using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and start playing around with a virtual machine.

Comment: As DJCrashdummy wroter your computer is not 32bit (intel i5). You can dual boot Ubuntu 64bit with  windows 32bit without expecting any problems, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

When users try to download Ubuntu ISO image, they see a notification message informing them that Ubuntu 64-bit is recommended and thus tend to think that a 4 Gb RAM is the only hardware condition they must have.

To run Ubuntu b4-bit release you must have both a compatible CPU and enough RAM for it.

If your processor is a 32-bit one then the Ubuntu 14.04 64-bits installer won't not **even** starts.

As you said, having 4 Gb is enough to run a 64-bits Ubuntu release. Even with a 2 Gb RAM you can run a 64-bits Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 (Note that [Ubuntu 12.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) has reached its **end of life**)

> 32bit and 64bit are types of architecture, 32 works in 4 sets of 8
>   (the 8 being a byte), and 64 in 8 sets of 8. More bits mean that data
>   is processed in larger chunks, resulting in greater speed and
>   accuracy.

To be sure of the nature of your processor, please run this command: `lscpu` which, in my case, outputs this:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            17
Model:                 3
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2100.000
BogoMIPS:              4200.56
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             64K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              512K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

The important line our case is:   `CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit` which thing means I both can install Ubuntu 64-bit and 32-bit.

For better understanding this [documentation](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-decide-if-you-should-use-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu) can be helpful.